Cannot modify MongoDb databases in Visual Studio Code
I have created an Atlas account and created some databases in the cloud including a Playground database.. The admin account is included in the connection string and I am able to list the databases in Visual Studio Code, browse their collections etc.
However, when I open a Mongodb shell and run command "show users" after selecting the either admin, or playground database I get the following error "(Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command." (See screenshot for complete error)
I am an AtlasAdmin, but have added 2 other admin permissions in case I am not admin enough. However I get the same error. I am on a Chromebook running the Linux virtual environment. What would prevent me from listing the users of the admin database, or any other database?[Visual Studio Code view]Permissions I have on my Atlas instance
I am expecting to be able to list users and perform other admin tasks on my databases.

Atlas now contains the user accounts for Mongodb, not the databases. Configure the user accounts in the Atlas cloud interface.
